# How to set document Permission (RMS)

Tags: .net, ms-word, ms-office, vsto, office-interop

Using Office you can set permissions on document from ribbon > File > Info > Protect Document >restrict Access. How I can do that from code?

In Outlook it is quit simple you can set MailItem.PermissionTemplateGuid

Word doesn't have such property it has Permission property object but i didn't found  any way to set the permission from policy.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

[Document.Protect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.protect(v=vs.120).aspx) method will solve your purpose.

**Document level addin**

```
this.Protect(Word.WdProtectionType.wdAllowOnlyReading, 
    ref noReset, ref password, ref useIRM, ref enforceStyleLock);
```

**Application level addin**

```
this.Application.ActiveDocument.Protect(
    Word.WdProtectionType.wdAllowOnlyReading,
    false, System.String.Empty, false, false);
```

Source and more explanation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178793.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: This is not what I want. The protect feature and RMS are two different things. And I want to use exactly the RMS feature.

Answer (score 0):

Document has a Permission object which has method ApplyPolicy which takes the name of file as parameter. The file should be the policy template file.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa432144(v=office.12).aspx